# Windows Folder/Desktop Widget

Tags: c#, windows, desktop

Is it possible to create an application that allows you to interact with the files/folder in any folder (including desktop) graphically?

IE: The program would allow you to create a graphical object that allows you to drag and drop folders/files on to it. The object would remain in the folder/desktop and basically be another folder with different capabilities.

I was thinking of a desktop widget, but wasn't sure where to look exactly.

Also, if this was possible, could it be done with C# in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but it seems that you will need to create shell extension and doing so in managed language is not recommended by Microsoft due to possible problems with .NET runtime initialization.